# Rav Heinemann Semicha

Tags: rabbis, semicha

Does anyone know what one should prepare himself with before taking a semicha bechina on Basar B'chalav with Rav Moshe Heinemann?

Comment: I heard he tests guys on pischei tshuvos

Comment: A few people who took their bechinos with Rav Heinemann told me they needed to know the Shulchan Aruch, Shach, Taz, and Pischei Teshuvos really well. Hatzlacha!

Comment: I heard he expects you to know every shach and taz by heart

Comment: You serious @robev?

Comment: Seemingly you should know all the material needed to paskin any question you'd be presented with in the topic. If he fails you anyway, it wasn't worth getting. Same with all semikha tests.

Comment: I received semicha from him. You have to know every shach, taz, and pischei teshuva. You don’t have to know them by heart verbatim (it is open book), but he expects to be able to find each one quickly and speak out the basic idea right away. Also, though it’s not officially part of the curriculum, he expects you to have dabbled in the relevant pri megadims.

Comment: How well do you have to know the pischei tshuvas? Like just the psak? Do you need to know the Sh"t that the pischei Tshuvah brings down etc...

Comment: @ASL I'm taking a test by him soon and I just wanted to know what to look at for. Thank you. Is there any seforim etc that were useful or did you just go through Sh"a rema shach taz pischei tshuvah stam?

Comment: @moshe מערכת השולחן is a Sefer that abbreviates the shach and taz. It’s certainly not a substitute for learning the whole thing, but is great for chazara. Pischei teshuvos, need to know basic psak.